# Counting the occurrences in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a simple array such as:

```
[
  "Selkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Selkatreeni",
  "Selkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Rintatreeni",
]
```

I want to display the element that has the highest occurrence, in this case "Jalkatreeni". How should I go about doing it? Any neat tips are appreciated. :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.
You can iterate through your array using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). In each iteration you take your whole array (`arr`) which is the fourth argument in the  `reduce()` and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that array for your accumulator (=the *result* of the reduce/our most frequent item in the array). If the length of the filtered `arr` is larger than the same filtered array but for the current iterated item (`curr`) we know our previous result (`acc`) occurs the most often. Otherwise we know it must be `curr` (the current iterated one). Finally we can return our new most frequent item so far and continue doing the same thing for the rest of the array.

Here's a working example:

```js
const data = [
  "Selkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Selkatreeni",
  "Selkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Jalkatreeni",
  "Rintatreeni",
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr, _, arr) =>
  arr.filter((item) => item === acc).length >
  arr.filter((item) => item === curr).length
    ? acc
    : curr
);

console.log(result);
```

In case you worry about the `_` argument. This is just used as a *placeholder* for the unneeded third parameter in order to access the fourth one ;)

Comment: If you don't mind expaining a bit what's happening in this reduce function I would highly appreciate it. I'm still having a bit trouble understanding reduce(), since I haven't used it much. :)

Comment: @niemax Explanations added ;) Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the elements in a Map with names as 'values' and frequency as 'keys' and use suitable function to find highest of keys and ultimately the value at that particular key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function mode(array)
{
    if(array.length == 0)
        return null;
    var modeMap = {};
    var maxEl = array[0], maxCount = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        var el = array[i];
        if(modeMap[el] == null)
            modeMap[el] = 1;
        else
            modeMap[el]++;  
        if(modeMap[el] > maxCount)
        {
            maxEl = el;
            maxCount = modeMap[el];
        }
    }
    return maxEl;
}
```

So, usage is like this:

```
highest_occurance = mode(array_var);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Joshua, I will take a look at this later. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the old school type then you can achieve this using a simple `for...of` loop. Have a look-

```js
const data = ["Selkatreeni","Jalkatreeni","Selkatreeni","Selkatreeni","Jalkatreeni","Jalkatreeni","Jalkatreeni","Rintatreeni"];

let track = {},
    max = 0,
    ans = '';

for (const name of data) {
  track[name] ||= 0; // This is equivalant to `track[name] = track[name] || 0`
  track[name]++;
  
  if (track[name] > max) {
    max = track[name];
    ans = name;
  }
}

console.log(ans);
```

Here, I am storing the encounters of a name into an object named `track` and then check if the name is maximum one or not.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I'm using react with a linter so it tells me not to use for of loops in this case. :D

Comment: I don't see any problem with react and linter. You can create a function that will return the name encountered maximum.